# Intermittent exception Could not initialize class org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager when start docker container on AWS Fargate

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, docker, log4j

Intermittently "Could not initialize class org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager" exception when running Fargate task.

Spring-boot application
Java base image

The application runs perfectly 90% of the time but every now and then with zero changes to the image stored in ECR it fails with

```
Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class 
org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager
```

I have ran the application locally but this issue has never occured.

How I create logger

```
 private static Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(CollectorController.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your main application

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

    @SpringBootApplication
    public class CollectorController {
        private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CollectorController.class);

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(IslandgreenApplication.class, args);
        }

    }
```

in your application.properties file add this

```
logging.file=C:/Users/A Majutharan/Documents/sun3/island_green/islandgreen/src/main/resources/\
  LogFiles/app.log(this is the storing path)
```